# Python Execute Input on Application

Tags: python, windows, input, exe

I have a Windows App (Exe) and i want to (for example) press Enter in this App.

Theres a method to click (for example with `pynput`), but im wondering if it is possible to only click in this one app. Just like Selenium where u can click in the browser...